# Convert XSD to datamodel

Tags: xsd, datamodel

I'm looking for converting XSD schema into datamodel. Do we know how to convert XSD into datamodel using any tool or some set of code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Data Model defines how to convert data to and from XML. Data Models are detected when they are stored in directory that has been registered to provide data models, these models then appear for us in tools.

DataModel looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<model>
  <strategyId>fixedlen</strategyId>
  <id>
    <part>Test</part>
  </id>
  <description>Description</description>
  <optionSet id="fixedlen" modelDefinitionType="definition">
    <optionSet id="section">
      <optionSet id="general">
        <option id="name">section</option>
        <option id="recordName">row</option>
        <option id="recordSeparator">{platform newline}</option>
        <compoundOption id="recordOwner">
          <option id="ownerType">greedy</option>
        </compoundOption>
      </optionSet>
      <optionSequence id="components"/>
    </optionSet>
  </optionSet>
</model>
```

Comment: 1) you are not showing us an XSD schema here, it is an XML instance. 2) what are you calling a datamodel?

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted an xsd schema, you've posted an XML representation of a data structure - or model as you've called it. However, assuming that is to be your input (or output) data structure, I suggest you do some research about [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) and Java to see if that library is suitable for your cause. It is possible to create a data structure from just a schema using this tool.

There is plenty existing documentation as well as several good quality questions/answers on this site.